# How to change wp_mail to subscribers email id

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am trying to setup a landing page on wordpress with a plugin - Coming Soon CC. It has a subscription box. Every time someone sign up for the newsletter I get an email from wordpress@mydomain.com with the notification. How can I change it in a way that I get a mail from the subscriber's mail id itself instead of wordpress@mydomian.com.In other words that it fetch's and sends a mail from the subscribers email id instead of wp_mail.
This is what I found in the plugin files -

```
/**
 * [ajax_newsletter_subscribe description]
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
public function ajax_newsletter_subscribe() {

    check_ajax_referer( 'cc-cs-newsletter-subscribe' );

    $to_email = $this->get_option('newsletter', 'email') ? $this->get_option('newsletter', 'email') : get_option( 'admin_email' );

    if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        $sent = wp_mail(
            $to_email,
            __('You have a new subscriber!', $this->plugin_slug),
            sprintf(__("Hello,\n\nA new user has subscribed through your Coming Soon page.\n\nSubscriber's email: %s", $this->plugin_slug), $_POST['email'])
        );

        if($sent) {
            print json_encode(array('status' => 'ok'));
            die();
        }
    }

    print json_encode(array('status' => 'error'));
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the email `$headers`, among which `From`:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . ' <' . $_POST['email'] . '>';

$sent = wp_mail(
    $to_email,
    __( 'You have a new subscriber!', $this->plugin_slug ),
    sprintf( __( "Hello,\n\nA new user has subscribed through your Coming Soon page.\n\nSubscriber's email: %s", $this->plugin_slug ), $_POST['email'] ),
    $headers
);
```

Check the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail#Using_.24headers_To_Set_.22From:.22.2C_.22Cc:.22_and_.22Bcc:.22_Parameters).

Comment: Hey diggy, thanks for the reply. Sorry i am a little new to coding, can you hep me what exactly should I place in the 'from" so it fetches the subscribers email id itself?